# Reset scope variable in recursion function in python

Tags: python, django, recursion

I have a model for tree like data (id - parent). And I have recursion method, to get all children for current page.

```
children = []    
class Page(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_children(self, include_self=True):
        global children
        if include_self:
            children.append(self.id)
        for c in Page.objects.filter(parent=self.id):
            c.get_children(True)
        return children
```

I use console for a test:

```
>>> from pages.models import Page
>>> q = Page.objects.get(id=10) #I get a page with children.
>>> q.get_children(False)
```

It works fine:

```
[12L, 11L]
```

But if I use this method next time,

```
q.get_children(False)
```

result will be:

```
[12L, 11L, 12L, 11L]
```

I want always have:

```
 [12L, 11L]
```

What is do wrong? How I should reset the variable but safe scope of recursion?

**EDIT:**

Correct recursion function is:

```
def get_children(self, include_self=True, children = None):
   if children is None:
        children = []
    if include_self:
        children.append(self.id)
    for c in Page.objects.filter(parent=self.id):
        c.get_children(True)
    return children
```

Comment: You are assuming that `children=[]` creates a new list every call; it doesn't. See the duplicate. Function defaults are created *once*.

Comment: The solution: use `children=None` (set to a sentinel), and in the function test for the sentinel, `if children is None: children = []`.

Comment: This not working too.

Comment: I add this:     def get_children(self, include_self=True):
        global children
        if children is None:
            children = []
        if include_self:
            children.append(self.id)
        for c in Page.objects.filter(parent=self.id):
            c.get_children(True)
        return children

Comment: Why would creating a *global* work? You then just shifted the problem to a different place (from a shared function default to a global). Please do read the duplicate carefully.